# Python Selenium web-driver supress console windows in tkinter application

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, console, microsoft-edge

I have made a simple GUI using tkinter library. When user click on a button the script is opening a new thread where a selenium library start to perform automated clicks on a webpage:

def start_button3_callback(self):

```
# create a new thread to run the button3_callback function in the background
t = threading.Thread(target=self.button3_callback)
t.start()
```

that is how I start the browser using selenium after the user click on button3

button3_callback:

```
options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-exit-on-background")
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
```

I compiled the application like this using cmd and pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --name Edge_Script -w --icon=myIcon_9.ico --add-binary "myIcon_9.ico;." --noconsole main.py
```

I want to start the selenium script without spawning an extra console window. I want this console window to be hidden for the user. However When a user start the start_button3_callback a console with this file location .cache\selenium\msedgedriver\win64\116.0.1938.69 spawns.

I was trying to use "--noconsole" in the pyinstaller but it does not seem to supress the windows from spawning.

I was also trying to add this option:

```
options.add_argument("--log-level=OFF")
```

but none of it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The window can be avoided by CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag. Also, you need to import Service for this flag:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as EdgeService 
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW

edge_service = EdgeService('/path/to/edgedriver')
# Use `edge_service.creationflags` instead for selenium < 4.6
edge_service.creation_flags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=edge_service)
```